# Hidden field losses value using jquery append

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

I have a modal in which I upload an image.
That image is then returned like this:

```
<input type="hidden" value="20130108A70WY2.jpg" name="image_message_file" id="image_message_file">
<img src="http://files.gestionradioqc.com/immedia/message/picture/2013/01/08/20130108A70WY2_300.jpg">
```

I then transfer the data to my main page using javascript like this:
<--EDITED-->

```
function addAttachmentsToMessage(){
    var picture = $("#image_message_preview").find('img').parent().html();
    alert(picture);
    if(picture != ''){
        $("#message_attachments").append("<div class='attachment cf'>"+
                                        "<ul class='att-picture cf'>"+
                                            "<li>"+picture+"</li>"+
                                        "</ul>"+
                                    "</div>");
        clearAttachments();
    }
}

function clearAttachments(){
    $("#image_message_file").attr('value', '');
    $("#image-message").attr('value', '');
    $("#image_message_loading").hide();
    $("#image_message_upload").show();
    $("#image_message_preview").hide();
}
```

<-- / EDITED-->

The alert is actually correct.
But what actually gets appended to message_attachments is (no value in the hidden field):

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="image_message_file" id="image_message_file">
<img src="http://files.gestionradioqc.com/immedia/message/picture/2013/01/08/20130108A70WY2_300.jpg">
```

But only the first image appended has that problem.
The others are ok.
I have the same issue on Firefox 17, on Chrome 23 and on IE 9.

Any ideas what my problem is?

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? Where are `image_message_preview` and `message_attachments`?

Comment: Are you missing the close of the `if` on purpose or as a code paste issue?

Comment: I found the mistake: I put a id on the hidden input and I had code (sadly not shown here) that was resetting the value back to "" according to the id. Thus changing only the first found field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my original post to show where the error came from.
The error came from my function clearAttachments() which was resetting the value of #image_message_file. Since it was searching by id, it was only changing the value of the first appended item.
Therefore, I removed that line and now everything works, thus the function is now:

```
function clearAttachments(){
    $("#image-message").attr('value', '');
    $("#image_message_loading").hide();
    $("#image_message_upload").show();
    $("#image_message_preview").hide();
}
```

Thanks for everybody's insights!

Answer (score 0):

`$("#image_message_preview")` is NOT accessing your markup as posted
SO picture alerts "undefined" -- so you must have paste code/markup issues?
"image_message_file"

I took the liberty of wrapping/proper nameing etc and it works to alert the value here:

http://jsfiddle.net/eBTYC/

Comment: It would appear that #image_message_preview is the parent container to the img and input. I guess he just didn't post that code.

Comment: @davidethell - yes, see my assumption of that in the fiddle...something else in play here or just bad syntax?  I don't know...but this was more than a comment would hold.

Comment: Agreed. I see nothing obviously wrong with the code so something is missing.

Comment: Sorry, my code was incomplete, and the alert was working, as stated in the original message.

Comment: I edited my original code to include what was causing the trouble. Thanks for your input.